# Infinispan Cross Site Replication send only Key of Removed Object

Tags: infinispan

I try use Infinispan 8.2.4 with crossite replication. It works but It sends only key for a removed object. I would like to receive full object in backup server (for example as Put Command).

I found this code in sources ([Link to github](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/infinispan/xsite/BackupSenderImpl.java#L316)):

```
} else if (writeCommand instanceof RemoveCommand && writeCommand.isConditional()) {
    filteredCommand = commandsFactory.buildRemoveCommand(((RemoveCommand) writeCommand).getKey(),
                                                           null,
                                                           writeCommand.getFlagsBitSet());
}
```

I would like to have such code

```
} else if (writeCommand instanceof RemoveCommand && writeCommand.isConditional()) {
    filteredCommand = commandsFactory.buildRemoveCommand(((RemoveCommand) writeCommand).getKey(),
                                                         ((RemoveCommand) writeCommand).getValue(),  
                                                          writeCommand.getFlags());
}
```

Is it bug of Infinispan? How should I send removed object from master site to backup site?

Comment: it isn't a bug. If the conditional remove is successful in the primary site, it doesn't need to send the removed value to the backup site. The backup site only needs the key to remove.

why do you need the removed object? what is your use case?

Comment: I need to delete record from DB in a custom interceptor. Now I get the entity with InvocationContext::lookupEntry. But it would be better to get entity from RemoveCommand::getValue

Comment: That is the way to go. Paying the cost of serializing and sending the removed value when you have it available in memory in the backup site, doesn't seems right. By the way, you can configure a DB in the persistence configuration and avoiding handling the DB interaction yourself. See http://infinispan.org/docs/8.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#persistence